# Track user changes in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table and a Form in MS Access. Data is added through the Form. I want to be able to track user changes. I have a column User in my table where the user name will be added after update of the Form. For this purpose I have the following VBA code which will be fired After Update of the form, however it doesnt work and I dont know where the mistake is. Help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
  Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()

Dim UserLogin As String
Dim MyId As Integer
Dim strSQL As String
Dim rs As Recordset

 UserLogin = Environ("Username")
 MyId = Me!ID.Value

 Set strSQL = "Update [MyTable] SET [MyTable]!User = '" & UserLogin & "' WHERE  [MyTable]!ID = '" & MyId & "';"
'Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can track changes not only in particular form, but any change made in data will be registered, even if it was done directly on table. Just create `Before Change` data macro for your table ("Create Data Macro" menu in table design mode.
In Data Macro designer add the action `SetField` with parameters: `Name = User` ("User" is your field name for storing user name) and `Value = GetUserName()`.

In any standard module create the function like this:

```
Public Function GetUserName() As String
GetUserName = Environ("Username")
End Function
```

After this any change in your table will update changed record by name of user, who did this change.

Please note, in case of split database this function should be available in front end and in back end databases if you want to edit data also in backend.

As of your code, check data type of ID field. If it's Number, remove single quotes. Also replace "!" by "." in SQL query text.

Comment: Actually Before Change data macro is not an option because I have couple of sql queries triggered After Update and they perform different changes to the table and the Data Macro will record all these changes to the user. I dont want the changes performed from the queries to be recorded to the user who for example changed only the phone number of customer. Since the User will enter and change all the data from the Form I think my AfterUpdate Sub above will work fine but I dont know how to call the Sub Procedure and all queries which I have at the same time in After Update event of the Form?

Comment: I just added (Cancel As Integer) because it wasnt working. Not it works perfectly.

Comment: I gave just an idea how to track changes, it was simplest code. Normally I add to the macro code, which allows to switch off logging (for bulk updates for instance) and it can determine, which field was updated and log significant changes only. Din't understand question about calling Sub procedire. From which code you are going to call Sub and which Sub?

Comment: The idea you gave for tracking changes with the data macro is great and simple but it is not working in my situation because after updating of the Form I have three queries fired and all changes made will be as if they are   made by the user. After this I decided to use the Sub which I asked at first for but I didnt know how to use it at he same time will all the queries in one After Update event. Finally I used the following which works fine Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.User = Environ("Username")
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Just insert a textbox with controlsource as "User"

and then instead of after update use

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate()
    me.user = Environ("Username")
end sub
```

no need for separate SQL operation